# Two definitions of the Incomplete Gamma Function - are they equivalent?

Tags: integration, gamma-function, actuarial-science

From *Loss Models*, 4th ed., by Klugman et al.:

> **Definition 5.5** The **incomplete Gamma function** with parameter $\alpha > 0$ is denoted and defined by
>   $$\Gamma\left(\alpha ; x\right) = \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int\limits_{0}^{x}t^{\alpha - 1}e^{-t}\text{ d}t\text{.}$$

I assume this is the "upper" incomplete Gamma function I've read about online. From [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html):

$$\Gamma(\alpha;x) = \int\limits_{x}^{\infty}t^{a-1}e^{-t}\text{ d}t\text{.}$$

Are these definitions equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're not equivalent.

The function in Klugman et al. should perhaps be called *the normalized lower incomplete gamma function*, and the function on MathWorld is commonly called *the upper incomplete gamma function*.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) and [the DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!

Comment: Also note that the integral in the first definition is often written using the lowercase gamma, i.e. $\gamma(\alpha, x)$ and with the upper case as we see with your second integral definition. The first is know as the 'lower incomplete gamma' and the later is the 'upper incomplete gamma'